# JavaFx: lookup doesn't find the correct Node

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have two Classes Highscore and HighscoreEinzelspieler. Highscore is the super Class where some logic for an table like view happens:

```
public VBox getDisplayHighscore(ArrayList<Spieler> spielerListe) {

    VBox output = new VBox();
    output.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    HBox headerRow = new HBox();

    Iterator<Spieler> iterator = spielerListe.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
        Spieler tmpPlayer = iterator.next();

        HBox tmpRow = new HBox();
        tmpRow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tmpRow.getStyleClass().add("tableRow");
        tmpRow.setId("tableRowId" + i); //um spaeter die neue Position oder den Gewinner zu markieren

        Label tmpName = new Label(tmpPlayer.getName());
        tmpName.getStyleClass().add("tableName");
        Label tmpVersuche = new Label("" + tmpPlayer.getVersuche());
        tmpVersuche.getStyleClass().add("tableVersuche");
        Label tmpTimer = new Label("" + tmpPlayer.getTimer());
        tmpTimer.getStyleClass().add("tableTimer");
        Label tmpPaare = new Label("" + tmpPlayer.getPaare());
        tmpPaare.getStyleClass().add("tablePaare");

        tmpRow.getChildren().addAll(tmpName, tmpVersuche, tmpTimer, tmpPaare);
        output.getChildren().addAll(tmpRow);
      }

    output.getStyleClass().add("table");
    return output;
}
```

Now I need this Function in my Subclass HinghscoreEinzelspieler (the part with the comments doesn't work):

```
public HighscoreEinzelspieler() throws IOException, NamenFehler, AlterFehler {
    // Liste auslesen
    ArrayList<Spieler> spielerListe = getHighscore();
    spielerListe.sort(new SpielerComparatorEinzel());
    playerDisplay = super.getDisplayHighscore(spielerListe);
    playerDisplay.getStyleClass().add("table");

    //Node highlight = Masterklasse.primaryScene.lookup("#tableRowId1");
    //System.out.println(highlight);
    //highlight.getStyleClass().remove("tableRow");
    //highlight.getStyleClass().add("tableRowWinner");

    // mittig einbinden
    Masterklasse.centerBox.getChildren().addAll(playerDisplay);

}
```

Now I want to find one line from the getDisplayHighscore I created.
For that I tried to get the line with the ID from my static scene with the function lookup("#tableRowId"+i). But I always get a "none", I tried it in the super class with:

```
output.lookup("tableRowId1")
```

and it worked. So I think the static scene is the problem.

Thanks,
Luka :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my late answer, I fixed it now. It was something with so code position, I have to call this method later. But I don't know why it's now working. I can't explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is `Masterklasse.primaryScene` but this should work:

```
playerDisplay.lookup("#tableRowId1");
```

If `Masterklasse.primaryScene` should point on your `output` you need to assign it in `getDisplayHighscore()` method:

```
Masterklasse.primaryScene = output;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I think I have the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. When I put the ID manually on the and it works: 

    `Node highlight = playerDisplay.lookup("tableRowId3"); `

But when I do something like this: 

    `int position = 3; 
    Node highlight = playerDisplay.lookup("tableRowId" + position);`

It doesn't find the element. 
Thank you!

Comment: I tried everything, to ensure that it's a String: 
`String playerPositionString = Integer.toString(playerPosition);
  String tableRowId = "tableRowId";
  tableRowId += playerPositionString;
  System.out.println((tableRowId instanceof String));`
And it returns true, so I don't know why it doesn't accept the concatenated string.

Comment: No idea, concatenation string and int always produces a string. Try to debug and go inside `lookup()` method with monitoring what the given id is and what the actual objects hierarchy you have.